# Removing all <h1> and </h1> from wp_post db

Tags: wordpress

Can someone help me remove all the header 1 tags (`<h1>` and `</h1>`) from my wp_post database?

I got a new theme, and on my old theme I will set `<h1>` tags manually on every single post.

Now the new theme makes a title `<h1>` automatically and I have multiple `<h1>` tags, which is bad for search engines.

How could I remove **ONLY** `<h1>` tags and not the text?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than crawling the database, you could write a filter to strip any `<h1>` or `</h1>` text that is found prior to displaying the title. This doesn't remove the source of the problem, but removes the effects.

For example:

```
function strip_title_h1( $title, $sep ) {
    $title = str_replace("<h1>","",$title);
    $title = str_replace("</h1>","",$title);
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'strip_title_h1', 10, 2 );
```

Note: you might need to change `"<h1>"` to `"&gt;h1&lt;"` or some other encoding if something's sanitised the html.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but there is no way to remove h1 from my wordpress post db ? Can i use this ? UPDATE table
SET post_content = CONCAT(SUBSTR(post_content, 1, LOCATE('<h1>', post_content) - 1),
    SUBSTR(post_content, LOCATE('</h1>', post_content) + 5));

Comment: Or this ? without deleting the text between <h1>Text</h1> : UPDATE wp_post SET post_content = replace(post_content, '<h1>', '' ) ;